# Can I cast other spells before a miracle?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm playing a red storm deck and I topdeck a [Reforge the Soul](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reforge%20the%20Soul). I only have 2 lands in play but have several rituals ([Pyretic Ritual](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pyretic%20Ritual), etc.) in my hand that I might want to cast to increase my storm count, since they will just be discarded anyway. Can I cast the rituals before I cast Reforge the Soul if I were to miracle it or must I pay the miracle cost and thus not be able to pay for the rituals?

Comment: While the existing answers cover the rules, note that in your specific case it is not useful, because this would be all done in the draw step, and all the remaining mana would be emptied from your pool when going to main phase, and by then you will have no mana sources left. You could of course still cast an instant spell with storm in the draw step, but not a sorcery.

Comment: As an extension to @Mephy's statement, there isn't a red instant with storm for 2 that makes this worth while.

Comment: @DrunkCynic They're casting rituals so it could be more than 2, and with Manamorphose it doesn't have to be red. I'm not sure how likely it is to help - a lot of the common cantrips are sorceries - but conceivably it's possible in the OP's deck and it doesn't hurt to cast them and see what you draw, right? (Or I know the OP didn't mention it, but you might want to cast them for Pyromancer Ascension.)

Comment: @Jefromi Every additional card expected to be in hand pushes this further into an edge case. For the Cheapest storm Instant, Brain Freeze, that's two Pyretic Rituals in hand with Reforge the Soul on the draw, then Manamorphose and Brain Freeze drawn by the Reforge the Soul Effect. It can happen, but it isn't something a deck should be built around.

Comment: @DrunkCynic Again, not saying it's common, just possible, so it's reasonable to ask. Even if all it does is give you a tiny chance of something awesome happening, there doesn't seem to be any downside to casting rituals and ending up with mana floating.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast your rituals before casting the miracle, though since it's your draw step, you'll have to spend any leftover floating mana during your draw step, i.e. on instants or activated abilities.

The full definition of Miracle is:

> 702.93a Miracle is a static ability linked to a triggered ability (see rule 603.10). “Miracle [cost]” means “You may reveal this card from your hand as you draw it if it’s the first card you’ve drawn this turn. When you reveal this card this way, you may cast it by paying [cost] rather than its mana cost.”

The static ability is the reveal-as-you-draw part: you make that decision as you draw the card, before the game progresses any further. If you do choose to reveal it, the rest of the ability triggers and goes on the stack. All that's really happened so far is the reveal.

That triggered ability (the "when..." in the definition) is where everything else happens. You cast the miracle card for its miracle cost when that ability *resolves*. So before that happens, you can respond to it with whatever you'd like, including your rituals, and you'll still get to cast it at the end. (As long as you're able to, anyway - for example if you discard it, you can't cast it anymore!) Once you're done with your rituals, you let the triggered ability resolve, and only then do you pay the miracle cost and cast it.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes, you can play an instant (such as pyretic ritual) just before you play  a miracle. Just note that you can only play instants not sorceries (or any permanent without flash) and that also you cannot play a land before you play the miracle or any other instants. So you must be able to have enough mana to cast the spells that you want without playing a land.

The right way to do it would be:

1. You draw your miracle card
2. You look at it and you decide to play it
3. You reveal your miracle card that you are playing, the miracle ability triggers.
4. With the miracle ability on the stack you respond to it by playing any number of instants. The instants will resolve first
5. Then when it is time to resolve the ability of the miracle card you pay for it is miracle cost, if you do then the spell resolves, you can also choose not to pay the miracle cost then you keep the card in your hand but you cannot cast it again for its miracle cost (you can cast it with the normal cost though).